# Can I cross-reference the variables of two different objects?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'll try to be as clear as possible.
Let's say I have these two Objects: Seller and Product

```
struct Seller {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Product {
    var type: String
    var sellerID: Int
}
```

And here are my two views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let seller = Seller(id: 42, name: "John")
    let product = Product(type: "Chair", sellerID: 42)
    @State var isShowingDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(product.type)
            .onTapGesture {
                isShowingDetail = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDetail) {
                ProductDetail(product: product)
            }
    }
}

struct ProductDetailView: View {
    let product: Product
    var body: some View {
        Text("This product was sold to me by: \(product.sellerID)") // I want to get the seller's name
    }
}
```

Is there a way to compare the values of Seller.id and Product.sellerID to get the value of Seller.name in my ProductDetailView?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: With this code the simplest solution is to pass the name as second parameter.

Comment: This is actually a simplified version of the code I'm working on. Basically I want the Product Chair to be connected to the Seller John

Comment: It is called a relationship. If you search the web for database structures and relationships you will find tons of info. The relationship is usually made by storing the id of of the item in each others structures. It could be an array if ids if the chair is available from multiple sellers or sellers have multiple chairs otherwise known as a to many relationship

Comment: How about `struct Product { var type: String; var seller: Seller}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question leaves a lot of questions that need answers to properly answer, however the easiest way to do it is to just pass the name, however I'm going to make a few assumptions.

> - You'll have multiple sellers.
> - You'll have multiple products.

With those assumptions in mind I suspect that you'll also have an array of each type, ex: `var sellers = [Seller]()` & `var products = [Product]()`. When working with something that matches/compares you need to break it down to your most basic functions, and that means to make some functions to handle that. Here are some functions I would make to handle that.

> - func getSeller(id: String) -> Seller {...}
> - func getProduct(id: String) -> Product {...}

With just those two functions we can pass in an ID for either a seller or a product and get back what we're expecting, but we can expand on that and use Swift's `Tuple` to get back exactly what we want, in a usable manner. There are other ways to do this, such as with `.map()` but I don't want to go that route because this is a fundamental skill and it shouldn't be glossed over.

> - func fetchByID(id: String) -> (Seller, Product) {...}

Doing a function like this would allow you to pass in any `id` and get back both the product & seller as a set. You would want to put this method wherever you have your seller array and product array, likely in your View Model.

```
func fetchByID(id: String) -> (Seller, Product)? {

    var matchedSeller: Seller?
    var matchedProduct: Product?
    
    for seller in sellers {
        if seller.id == id {
            matchedSeller = seller
        }
    }

    for product in products {
        if product.id == id {
            matchedProduct = product
        }
    }

    if matchedSeller != nil && matchedProduct != nil {
        return (matchedSeller, matchedProduct)
    }

    //This would be run if there is a mismatch or an ID can't be found. 
    //Would probably be wise to handle this appropriately. 
    return nil
}
```

Ultimately in your view, you would call it like so.

```
let seller = Seller(id: 42, name: "John")
let product = Product(type: "Chair", sellerID: 42)

//NOTE! - You need to make sure that your [Seller] & [Product]
//are accessible wherever your `fetchById(...)` is called. 

//0 would be the seller. 
//1 would be the product. 
var body: some View {
    //CAREFUL, handle the possible nil
    Text(fetchById(product.sellerID)!.0.name)
}
```

Honestly, there are many different ways to approach this problem, and this is a simple way to do it, although I'm not sure exactly why you want to handle it like this. Finally, always take a problem and break it down into its individual parts and create a small function for each part, that will make things become much easier for you. Forgive any syntax, I did this off the top of my head.